# Can I synchronize files between remote folders using native Python/pywin32?

Tags: windows, python-2.7, duplicates, lan, file-management

I am on a desktop machine with access to a remote file server (both Windows). Read/write access is granted on login, I do not need to re-enter username and password.

I want to:

- copy several very large files from one remote folder to another
- (the destination folder may contain a duplicate of an incoming file)
- avoid generating unnecessary network traffic
- (including not copying duplicates)

Currently I perform a blind `shutil.copy2()` for all files. This means duplicates are copied unnecessarily. The sysadmin also reports that this generates unnecessary network traffic as data is copied from *remote-folder-1* to *local-memory* to *remote-folder-2*.

Is there an existing command in native Python or pywin32 that accounts for these requirements?

---

Discarded options include [CopyFileEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363852%28VS.85%29.aspx) via pywin32 (which doesn't have duplicate checking), and native Python [byte-checking](https://docs.python.org/2/library/filecmp.html) or [checksumming](https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html) (which still read the files and thereby generate network traffic).

Fallbacks include recording checksums, [`stat`-based comparison](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/filecmp.py#l59) (without byte-checking), and optimistic (partial) checksumming.

Comment: Would it be possible to create a package for both sides of this environment? Much like rsync requires software on the other to be effective, would it be possible to "install" a script on both machines and do negotiation via sockets? This would solve the network load issue by the two scripts syncing what files are in need of transfer before actually transferring anything. If not, you could use `pywin32` to execute `WMI` commands on the remote machine and get checksums. That solves half your issue at least.

Answer (score 0):

Windows has a few stock solutions for sync - [offline files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/bb530660%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [briefcase](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/sync-using-briefcase#1TC=windows-7) ([deprecated since Win8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Briefcase_%28Microsoft_Windows%29)), [sync center](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317285%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ([new in Vista](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/keep-everything-in-sync-with-windows-vistas-sync-center/)). The 2nd appears to have [only a limited API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776781%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) while the others' appear quite complete. If you don't want to use any of them, you gonna go with 3rd party solutions. Python can work with any of them (e.g. with `ctypes`).

Python itself doesn't have data sync in the standard library (as it's quite a custom task, apparently). There are more than a few 3rd party modules for that, naturally.